# Connecting a UIView to a UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView subclass which contains some labels, a tableview, and a few other bits an pieces. It is currently the delegate and datasource for the tableview, and also manages many UI actions, none of which rely on data.  For example, when an 'edit' button is pressed, it knows how to update its controls, but it won't do anything when 'save' is pressed besides switch the controls back to the previous state.  All of this is done in code, I'm not using IB at all in this application.

I now want to plumb in all the data model changes that it can provoke.  But I would like to put these in a new controller class, which I guess is the MVC compliant way to do things. I'm not sure how to get there.

First, I need to create a custom controller class.  Should I be exposing from the UIView subclass a few of the controls so that the view controller can access them? For example, I will need to read and write to a textfield in the view, so should I provide a getter/setter for this?

Secondly, the tableview - instead of the UIView being the delegate, should I expose this also, and make the view controller the delegate? I.e. view.tableView.delegate = self from the UIViewController?

And finally, how do I launch the view from another view? Specifically, this is a paged scrollview application similar to the weather app, so I have a mainView UIView that specifies the single paged scrollview and then adds multiple custom UIViews, one for each page.  How do I replace [scrollView addSubview:myCustomView] and instead add the viewController?  And how do I connect the view to it's controller and vice versa?

I've not tried all of this without IB before so thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad, and part of the answer would depend on how you code your solution.  I will try replying with **a few hints of what works for me**:

**View:** As a general rule of thumb, keep in mind that a view object should be something very generic, that knows nothing about other views outside of its own hierarchy.  As such, a view should not rely on any specific interaction with other views, but rather communicate back to its delegate / owner / creator through callbacks, protocols, blocks, etc, when needed.

**View Controller:** Any time you need to make two views in different hierarchies interact with one another, my suggestion is that you stick to handling that interaction through the view controller.  By doing so, you'd be making sure your view is not contaminated by code that would be useless in a different screen.

Also please keep in mind that UIViewController for iOS is intended to be a class that you use for handling the complete visible view hierarchy, as opposed to acting as the controller for a single view.  As such, I recommend that you don't attempt have a controller for each view, but rather a single one to handle them all.

**Publishing view elements:** How much a UIView exposes as public in its header file is up to your implementation.  Any method that handles the way the view looks, that looks to be generic and reusable, and that doesn't need anything from outside the scope of the view's tree, is surely something you want to include in it's implementation and publish in the header file.

The same goes for any property that you feel is highly probable that someone from the outside will need to access.

Suggestion: publish only what's really needed.  Usually publishing new methods and properties is easier than removing them later on.